# Preserving objects through actions in Struts2

Tags: struts2

Can I preserve object across actions in Struts2 without using session?

I'm working on a Struts2 project and curious if there are some ways to preserving object
value once an action is ended.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Calling an action to read from an uploaded file and prepare its contents as a list of objects.
2. Then I display the list as an example for the user.
3. Then the user can click on a submit button to call an action to process the list which is created from the first action.

Usually the list would be lost once the action is end. So, I have to store the list as a session, but I think it should have some better methods to achieve the I'm working on.

Comment: provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). If the objects are strings, you can always pass em as parameters or recreate em. no need to clutter up the session with unnecessary objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve data across requests the session is the normal mechanism for doing so.

If you don't use the session you'd need to essentially duplicate its functionality to maintain the data associated with the current user/conversation.

Comment: Without session, I have to reproduce the list again?

Comment: @BhoomtawathPlinsut It has to come from somewhere, why not the session? You could recreate it, submit it in a form and use type conversion, or invent some other mechanism.

Comment: Thank you. I'm just too worry about session management and when should I destroy sessions. So, I try to avoid using session.

Comment: @BhoomtawathPlinsut You should destroy the session only on logout. There are a variety of ways to manage session objects; I rarely keep enough in session to be genuinely concerned, but you can always create an interceptor that removes named objects from the session on a per-action basis, configurable via annotations, XML config, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to *preserve* the List, then you *have* to use the Session.

But if you (if I've understood your problem) just need to handle the List through

> ActionOne (that creates the List) ->
>
> JSPOne (thast shows the List to the user) ->
>
> ACtionTwo (that receives the List from JSPOne and does some business with it)

, without having to worry about the fact that the user can change the List client-side (for example manipulating the web page with FireBug), then you don't need the session.

You just need the List object to be declared on ActionOne and ActionTwo (with getters and setters, at least the getter on ActionOne and at least the setter on ActionTwo), and to include List name and index on `name` attribute of JSP tags.
If you just draw it (like with `<s:property/>` tag), instad of using some tag that will post the value, like `<s:textfield />`, then just use an `<s:hidden />` to post te value.

For example, if you have:

```
List<MyObject> myList //with getters and setters
```

and assuming that MyObject has `id` and `value` fields (with getters and setters),

in JSP instead of

```
<s:iterator value="myList" >
   <s:property value="id"/>
   <s:textfield name="value"/>
</s:iterator>
```

use

```
<s:iterator value="myList" status="ctr" >
   <s:hidden name="myList[#ctr.index].id" value="id"/>
   <s:property value="id"/> <!-- no need here, you won't post this -->
   <s:textfield name="myList[#ctr.index].value" value="value" />
</s:iterator>
```

You will eventually validate a List like this throught the *Visitor Validator* (somewhewre in the future after all the rest is done :)

Enjoy

Comment: Thank you. Look like session is the answer for me.